# Configuration of ADC Renesas RX62N

Tags: c, embedded, touchscreen, adc, renesas-rx

I am using a [Renesas RX62N](https://archive.ph/1uhyX); my screen uses ADC unit 1 and my code uses Unit 0.

Is it so that the two ADC units cannot work together? When I run the "ADC" and the "Display code" separately it works fine but as soon as I try to integrate them and get the ADC values on screen the variable stops to read!. Any solutions?

Comment: How do you expect that we can present a solution to a question without any relevant informations?

Comment: I just wanted to know that is it so that in a controller the two ADC units cannot work together?

Comment: Why there should be two ADC units implemented, when they can't work together? Perhaps they share some sources like clocks or references but that should be clear after reading the datasheet. It could help if you show your code

Comment: It seems a little unlikely that the chip designers would include two ADC's if only one could be used at a time.

Comment: The URL in the question now gives you a 404 - Renesas apparently had a huge website reorganisation in 2020 and didn't have all of the old URLs redirect. I've checked and there's an archived copy at https://archive.ph/1uhyX

Comment: OK, it seems that in 2019 it was redirecting to https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rx/rx600/rx621-62n.html - and *that* now redirects to https://www.renesas.com/in/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/rx-32-bit-performance-efficiency-mcus/rx621-32-bit-microcontroller-100mhz-high-speed-operation-and-built-connectivity-functions-such-ethernet - which is a bit odd, since the old page focused equally on the 621 and 62N and the new page is devoted to the 621.

Comment: Finally, when the edit queue stops being full, someone needs to make a tag edit and add [renesas-rx] (EDIT: I've now been able to submit that edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the [user manual](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/mah/rx62n-group-rx621-group-users-manual-hardware-rev140?language=en&r=1054421) indicates that you can use either the one 12 bit ADC or two 10 bit ADCs, but you cannot select the 10 and 12 bit ADCs simultaneously.

Comment: Thankyou I was able to solve the issue. The problem as you pointed was that the 12 and the 10 bit adcs cannot work together and moreover all the channels in the 12bit are used up by my touchscreen. So by adding timers,delays and using DMAC I was able to finally get my ADC data to the display screen.

Comment: The link in this answer is now out-of-date after Renesas's website reorganisation. There's an up-to-date link to the latest version (1.40) of that manual at https://www.renesas.com/document/mah/rx62n-group-rx621-group-users-manual-hardware-rev140?language=en&r=1054421

Comment: @AJM Thanks; updated link.  However the link is not essential to the answer - anyone using the part should already have the documentation.  It was more of a gentle RTFM nudge ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all for your suggestions and time.

I was able to solve the issue. The problem as you pointed was that the 12 and the 10 bit adcs cannot work together and moreover all the channels in the 12bit are used up by my touchscreen. So by adding timers,delays and using DMAC I was able to finally get my ADC data to the display screen.

Regards 
Ashish